# What is the difference between getChildrenCategories() and getChildren()

Tags: category, collection

I am trying to create my own category menu.

If I use `getChildrenCategories()`, it shows the categories by position in the admin but can't sort if the category is included in the navigation or not

```
$category->getIncludeInMenu() is not working
```

However if I use the `getChildren()`, it can sort if it is included in the navigation but can't sort the position in the admin.

What is the difference between `getChildrenCategories()` and `getChildren()`?

How can I use them in order to achieve these following:

- Sort category by position in the admin.
- Check if included in the navigation.

Comment: Which version of Magento are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Explaining the difference:
In both Magento 1 and magento 2 the `getChildrenCategories` method from the category models returns a collection of child categories, where each element in the collection is a category instance.

`getChildren` returns the list of ids of the child categories of the current category.

Explaining why `getIncludeInMenu` does not work:

When calling `getChildrenCategories` the category elements in the collection that is returned do not contain every attribute the category has.
Take a look at the method `getChildrenCategories` from the category resource model.

You will see for both M1 and M2 that only the attributes `url_key`, `name`, `all_children`, `is_anchor` and `position` (via the sort option) are added. In M1 this happens in the method `_getChildrenCategoriesBase` and in M2 directly in `getChildrenCategories`

For M1 you can rewrite the method `_getChildrenCategoriesBase` and for M2 rewrite `getChildrenCategories` and add the attribute `include_in_menu` to the collection of categories.

Comment: Good explanation +1